# Is this SE suitable to discuss [country]'s law, even if it is non-english speaking?

Tags: discussion

For years we wanted to start a stackexchange for [country]'s law exactly like this, but with [insert number below 100m] people we naturally don't have a chance to create one on its own. Like [country], several other countries also don't have the mass to start its own stack exchange for their law. Until we found this Beta.

I searched on the help center and I didn't saw any problem in adding Q&As about the law of [country]. However, there are a couple of points that I would like to bring before trying to create a community of people from [country] in this SE:

A) Contrary to other stack exchanges, there is no common element besides being "Law". I.e. Programming is global, English is global, Physics is global, Math is global, but law (except international law) is always in respect to a specific country or region. Thus, every question should contain a country-tag (e.g. [usa](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa), [canada](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canada), [uk](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk)) that identifies the country (when the tag is missing, it means USA). Do we agree on this?

B) I didn't found any specific rule regarding the language in the help center, and I confirmed that this [is an ongoing discussion](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/3095) on Meta. Do we agree that we should write in English, that any relevant citation of the law can be kept in the country's language, but it should be summarised in english?

The thing is that SE is the best tool to community-based Q&A, and this SE seems like the right place for all those questions about [country]'s law. On the other hand, we don't want to disrupt the existing rules of this SE.

Comment: I don't think there is a language require for the law question to be on topic

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe there's any issue, as long as the substantive body of the post is in English (in addition to the source language, if applicable), as per [this Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/260340) post:

> > It is not, nor has it ever been, our goal to be the one place in the world for all programming information in every possible human language.
>
> - Direct question posters to native language resources.
>
>   - It is not the community's goal to teach English.
>   - The question asker should put some effort into the question.
>
> As long as the question is in salvageable English and makes some modicum of sense, it should be edited and improved like any other post.
>
> ...
>
> **I say keep it in English**. I'm not against diversity or other languages, I'm **for** us all being able to communicate under one. This isn't political, this isn't about smothering peoples cultures with Western ideologies. It is about being pragmatic.

I tend to agree with the majority of the answers in response to that post, except that unlike programming, law is not so English-oriented. Certainly, [as we've previously discussed](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/58) there seems to be a willingness to see the original documents in the source language, and indeed we've had a couple of examples of non-English jurisdiction questions

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the person who is writing a question on Law beta, with the body being in English, has the ability to translate the statutory portion if they are citing a law that is not in English. Further, I can easily look up statutes from non-English speaking countries, and because I am in the U.S. (it must be my IP address, or maybe my legal search engine's setting are in English) it is translated in English already. I also have seen other free sites that have the text of say, German, statutes readily available in English.

Pertaining to why it should be in English, I couldn't put it any better than @jimsug answer above. If you want a broad audience, and you want the question/answer to be one that will exist in perpetuity and presumably help others from whatever nation state the query's law arises out of, it almost needs to be in English. Otherwise, you just wouldn't get the exposure, nor the ability for most users to read, let alone answer, your question.