# What is the language scope of SE.Law?

Tags: discussion, scope

If have a question about a specific law, but I have doubts whether or not Law.SE is the right place to ask. It is about a German law called 'Impressumspflicht', for which could not even find an English translation. The [wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impressumspflicht) about it also does not link to articles in other languages. Therefore, I even doubt it would make sense to ask my question in English. The [help center](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) unfortunately does not cover this.

Finally, let me ask my question in a more generalized form:

Is Law.SE meant for questions in English and about laws that are relevant to English speaking people (and therefore not some obscure German law)? Or should I just go ahead and ask my question and see what happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would it be relevant to write questions in English in that case?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-would-it-be-relevant-to-write-questions-in-english-in-that-case)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[StackOverflow has an old policy on the use of foreign languages in Q&A](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/).  [One clever post on Meta pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226732/241697) that computer languages aren't English either, so [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) offers a vast body of reasonably analogous examples on how to discuss questions about other languages in English.

My attempt to translate the evolved policy on this to Law.SE follows:

**Questions and answers should be written in English *to the extent possible*, but questions about laws and legal concepts from any language can be on-topic.**

E.g., you can ask a question about "Impressumspflicht," but the question itself should be asked in English, which means that somewhere in the body of the question you'll probably have to attempt an English explanation of what the relevant elements of *Impressumspflicht* say.

[Here's the first example I found of a (good) Q&A involving German law](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/4045/10).

And [here's a good answer that addresses the general problem of translating legal concepts between languages](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/6438/10).